# What does 'duang' mean in 'online Chinese'?

Tags: word, slang, internet-slang

I see this word popping up on Weibo and Taobao. It's not written with any character, but spelled out in Pinyin. What does it mean?

EDIT:

For the annals:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if the "*mandarin*" tag really works here or not...haha...it's Jackie Chan we're talking about after all!

Comment: Well, If you read 'duang' on taobao.com, it has definitely made it into Mandarin slang. State media has also used it.

Comment: It will pass quickly. I've seen words like this many times. This one doesn't have the attribute to last.

Comment: A lot of non-Mandarin slang is found all over the place, doesn't make it *mandarin*.

Comment: Way before the Internet, "duang", (an onomatopoeia), has been used to indicate something that happens or springs up suddenly. "Duang" would be what a coiled spring under tension would sound like if it uncoils quickly. Like "twang".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/duang-how-jackie-chan-helped-780040

Citation, with explanation of the word in bold:

> Think that your hair is looking particularly good today? In Chinese
>   popular culture, it's looking "duang."
>
> A Chinese phrase that came out of nowhere, "duang" has taken the
>   Internet by storm, even though many don't really know its origins.
>
> We do know where "duang" started though. It was Hong Kong action star
>   Jackie Chan, who in 2004 was featured in a shampoo infomercial, where
>   he spread his hands and described how his sleek dark locks would
>   simply "duang" after a scrub with Bawang organic shampoo. **A useful
>   way of translating the word is as "boing," in the sense of "bouncy and
>   vibrant," or even "ta-da!"**
>
> A parody video making fun of the old commercial recently hit the web,
>   making the word a social media trend. It's been widely interpreted as
>   "cool," and the word resurfaced again recently after Chan posted it on
>   his Weibo page. It has become to Chinese slang what Kim Kardashian's
>   rear end is to U.S. popular culture. It's breaking the Internet as
>   Chinese pop stars are called "duang pretty" and the like.
>
> Although it's a long way from featuring in a dictionary, it's been
>   used millions of times on the Chinese social network Weibo and has
>   been looked up 1.5 million times on China's biggest search engine,
>   Baidu.
>
> In case you're "duang confused," you just need to know that
>   "everyone's "duang-ing" and it's great" or "This is so duang hot" are
>   the kinds of comments you see on the Weibo social network these days.
>
> There have also been numerous mash-up videos, and apparently during
>   the visit of Britain's Prince William to China last week, he was
>   greeted by some people saying "duang, duang," because the English
>   gentry look is seen as cool in China.

Comment: apparently you can also "duang" something- meaning adding extra whiz-bang to it. I think.

Comment: @MasterSparkles  In that sense, the English translation would be "zhoosh it up."  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zhoosh

Comment: @ColinMcLarty- I stand corrected, good sir.

Comment: Hollywood Reporter is kind of making it into a bigger thing than it actually is, I'm sure everyone will have forgotten about duang by next week....

Comment: "has been looked up 1.5 million times on China's biggest search engine" Where can you look up Baidu search statistics? I mean not the search results stats, but how many times a term has been queried? Something like Google Trends or Google Adwords Keyword Planner.

Comment: 百度指数- index.baidu.com . don't have time to log in and confirm, but looks like what you want.

Comment: I think the only way of using it that makes sense is using it as a single onomatopoetic word like in 'Duang! Now they are twice as big.' Other usages are floating around. But I think that's just the cyber populations trying to make most fun out of it, but using it as a verb doesn't really seem as much catchy and could be confusing. (native Mandarine speaker)

Answer (score 5):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ModL1vD1A7U

It means cool, damn or whatever you want it to mean. Informally, the character is 成 over 龙, that is after the innovator.

Answer (score 3):

Following what 倪阔乐 mentioned, here is a helpful visualization for how the newly formed pseudo-character looks like:
[image: duang]